# kendo.directives module not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

We are building a TreeView in our angular js application, for which we decided to use kendo ui.

```
var TabWareApp = angular.module('TabWareApp', ['kendo.directives']);
```

In BundleConfig.cs,

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo").Include(
            "~/Scripts/kendo/2014.1.318/kendo.all.min.js"));
```

in the HTML

```
<div class="box-col">
            <h4>TreeView</h4>
            <div kendo-tree-view="tree"
                 k-data-source="treeData">
            </div>
        </div>
```

In the controller,

```
$scope.treeData = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: [
           { text: "Item 1" },
           {
               text: "Item 2", items: [
               { text: "SubItem 2.1" },
               { text: "SubItem 2.2" }
               ]
           },
           { text: "Item 3" }
    ]
});
```

We are seeing the Modulerr error

> ### "Module 'kendo.directives' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument."

Please Help!!!!

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Using the Treeview without the Kendo.directives,  
     **$("#treeview-left").kendoTreeView({
                    dataSource: [],
                    select: function (e) {
                        
                    }
                });**